# Twitter error - verify_credentials request fails but tweeting and other endpoints still accessible

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, ios6

I'm trying to access the user's credentials of Twitter with this code:

```
ACAccountStore *account = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *accountType = [account accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

    [account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil
                                  completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
     {
         if (granted)
         {
             NSArray *arrayOfAccounts = [account accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

             if ([arrayOfAccounts count] > 0)
             {
                 ACAccount *twitterAccount = [arrayOfAccounts lastObject];

                 NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https:api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json"];


                 SLRequest *getRequest = [SLRequest
                                           requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter
                                           requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                           URL:requestURL parameters:nil];


                 [getRequest setAccount:twitterAccount];


                 [getRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {

                     NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
                     NSLog(@"Twitter Response : %@ ",json);


                 }];

             }
         };
     }];
}
```

With this code I'm getting this error:

```
Twitter Response : {
errors =     (
            {
        code = 32;
        message = "Could not authenticate you";
    }
);
```

}

The weird thing is that, if I try to tweet something, or access some other endpoint of Twitter, where it's required to have an oauth-token, the operation ends successfully.

Answer (score 0):

try this

TwitterResponse twitterResponse1 = TwitterStatus.Update(tokens, "test", new StatusUpdateOptions { APIBaseAddress = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/", UseSSL = true });